# Separate web links from paragraph into a JS array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I checked all answers above to see if mine was answered , please don't tag this as duplicate

In the application that i am building there is a div

```
<div class="paragraphlink"> </div>
```

I am allowing users enter any text like this

> Räikkönen was among the two Formula One drivers **http://www.formula1.com** who made it into the Forbes magazine's The Celebrity 100 list, the other being Fernando Alonso **http://www.google.com**. He is 36th on Forbes magazine's **http://www.forbesmagazine.com**

If you notice there are urls present in the above para. can you please help me with a javascript code to extract all the urls from the para above?

Comment: How is this *not* a duplicate of about a million questions? Where are you having problems exactly and why do the other solutions not work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can RegExp object

```
var reg = new RegExp(/http(s)?:\/\/[a-z0-9_-\.\/]+/ig);

var html = "Räikkönen was among the two Formula One drivers http://www.formula1.com who made it into the Forbes magazine's The Celebrity 100 list, the other being Fernando Alonso http://www.google.com. He is 36th on Forbes magazine's http://www.forbesmagazine.com"

html.match(reg);
```

will return you an array of urls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the match function on your text to extract url as for example:

```
var str = "Räikkönen was among the two Formula One drivers http://www.formula1.com who made it into the Forbes magazine's The Celebrity 100 list, the other being Fernando Alonso http://www.google.com. He is 36th on Forbes magazine's http://www.forbesmagazine.com";

var urls = str.match(/http(s)?:\/\/[a-z0-9_-\.\/]+/ig);
// now the var "urls" is in array with your URL
```

But the regex is simple here, you can find a better on many website.

Answer (score 0):

use regular expressions

Regular expression like this

```
     /(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/g
```

will match urls

For more on Javascript regex check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) and [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re.shtml)